# Is there a difference between "seeks" and "tries"?

Tags: synonyms, verb-agreement, grammatical-roles

I am seeking guidance on using *seek* vs *try* when speaking.

This sentence is talking about what a research study is attempting to discover:

> A flu challenge study **tries** to understand what happens when a person is infected with flu virus and how the body controls the infection.

or

> A flu challenge study **seeks** to understand what happens when a person is infected with flu virus and how the body controls the infection.

Is there a difference?

Comment: Include in the question what you found in a dictionary.

Comment: In this context the words mean pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Both are metaphors. No seeking or trying (or understanding) is involved; studies are not animate and do not have perception or volition. What the writer is trying to do is to explain what the general purpose of this kind of test is, and they're trying to personify it by using human-subject verbs. The result is as you see.

Comment: Is one more or less correct than another? Or is there a better way to say it?